# python zeep HTTPError: 405 Client Error: method Not Allowed for url:

Tags: python-3.x, salesforce, zeep

I'm trying to use python zeep to bring down salesforce data via soap API. I'm getting the error: python zeep HTTPError: 405 Client Error: method Not Allowed for url:

I have used postman to test getting the soap data from salesforce, I copied the python request code from postman for getting the token and running the query. I'm getting a subset of results.

Starts like this
    `<soapenv:Header> <LimitInfoHeader> <limitInfo> <current>234</current> <limit>5000000</limit> <type>API REQUESTS</type> </limitInfo> </LimitInfoHeader> </soapenv:Header> <soapenv:Body> <queryResponse> <result> <done>false</done> <queryLocator>0r8xx1w8R7PfKkHAIV-24</queryLocator>`

at the bottom I have:
`<size>408</size>`

I'm unable to figure out how to use the queryMore with request.

So I'm trying to do this with zeep and it appears that zeep is using just the url and not post. Unless I'm doing something wrong.

I would be happy to use request if I can figure out how to use the queryMore until done is true.